# Move files from trash to folder in python using Mac OS

Tags: python, macos

```
trash = "~/.Trash"
new_folder = []
for current_file in os.listdir(trash):
    new_folder.append(current_file)
```

The above code is not working.  I am trying to move files from the trash to a folder in python on a Mac.  The error message I'm getting is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.Trash'
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the `~` is a feature of your shell. Your can not use it like a normal file system path. Luckily Python has a function to assist you with that:

```
trash = os.path.expanduser('~/.Trash')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser for details.